# PHP: Sending Variable from Dropdown to URL

Tags: php, mysql, url

I kindly ask for your input in how to send a variable via URL to an other PHP site:

```html
  <form action="deny.php" method="get">
  <div align="left"></div>
  <p><span class="style13" style="height: 23px;">
    <select name="deny" class="style28" style="width: 320px">
      <option value="Select" selected="selected">Select</option>
      <option value="Price">Too expensive</option>
      <option value="Agency">Other Agency</option>
    </select>
    </span></p>
  <p><span class="style13" style="height: 23px;">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value=<? echo $id; ?> />
  </span> </p>
  <p>
  <? echo '<td><a href="deny.php?submit='.$id.'&deny='.$_GET['deny'].'">Send Feedback</a></td>'; ?>
  </p>
</form>
```

`$id` is correct, but `$deny` is empty

I even tried with `$deny (instead of $_GET['deny']) and $_POST[deny]` - but `$deny` is always empty. (can be controlled in the link)

Thanks for your suggestions!

BR,

Stefan

Comment: you can't use a link to submit (without js) the form, change <a> to <input type="submit"..>

Answer (score 2):

Replace your code with below one:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="deny.php" method="get">
  <div align="left"></div>
  <p><span class="style13" style="height: 23px;">
    <select name="deny" class="style28" style="width: 320px">
      <option value="Select" selected="selected">Select</option>
      <option value="Price">Too expensive</option>
      <option value="Agency">Other Agency</option>
    </select>
    </span></p>
  <p><span class="style13" style="height: 23px;">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
  </span> </p>
  <p>
  <a href="#" id="feedbackLink">Send Feedback</a>
  </p>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('select[name="deny"]').change(function(){
            var link = 'deny.php?submit=<?php echo $id; ?>&deny=';
            $('a#feedbackLink').attr('href', link + $(this).val());
        });
        $('select[name="deny"]').trigger('change');
    });
</script>
```

You can't use $_GET, $_POST, etc. variables without submitting form.

Hope this will resolved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

`$_GET['deny']` won't be populated until you submit the form to the current script.

Don't try to use PHP to construct the URL. Let the browser do it. Just put a submit button in the form and have appropriate inputs and action. That's what forms are for.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="deny.php" method="get">
  <div align="left"></div>
  <p><span class="style13" style="height: 23px;">
    <select name="deny" class="style28" style="width: 320px">
      <option value="Select" selected="selected">Select</option>
      <option value="Price">Too expensive</option>
      <option value="Agency">Other Agency</option>
    </select>
    </span></p>
  <p><span class="style13" style="height: 23px;">

  </span> </p>
  <p>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments and suggestions. I tried it with this echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='" . $id . "'>"; now everything will be passed, but the button name is the value of the id instead of the name "send feedback"... :-)

Comment: which text you want to display on button?

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="deny.php" method="get">
    <div align="left"></div>
    <p>
        <span class="style13" style="height: 23px;">

            <select name="deny" class="style28" style="width: 320px">
                <option value="Select" selected="selected">Select</option>
                <option value="Price">Too expensive</option>
                <option value="Agency">Other Agency</option>
            </select>
        </span>
    </p>
    <p>
         <span class="style13" style="height: 23px;">
              <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" /> 
         </span>
    </p>
    <p>
         <input type="submit" value="Send Feedback" value="submit" />
    </p>
</form>

 <?php
      if (isset($_GET)) {
          var_dump($_GET);
      }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="/deny.php?id=<? $id ?>" method="get">

<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Feedback" />
```

Did the trick :-)

Thanks,

Stefan

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,it has been tested.

```
<form action="your_page.php" method="GET"> <!--you may use POST for security as well -->
      <select name="deny">
        <option value="">Select Option</option>
        <option value="Price">Too expensive</option>
        <option value="Agency">Other Agency</option>
      </select>
      <!-- you msut have $id = something -->
      <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" /> 
      <input type="submit" value="Send Feedback" value="submit" />
  </form>

 <?php
      echo "<pre>";print_r(($_GET));
 ?>
```